# swal on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert

The following `example ONE` is from https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/. While clicking anywhere outside of the alert box, the alert box won't go away. That's what I expected.

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});
```

Another `example TWO` is from https://sweetalert2.github.io/. It behaved in another way. While clicking anywhere outside of the alert box, the alert box is gone.

```
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  type: 'info',
  html:
    'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags',
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  focusConfirm: false,
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Great!',
  confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs up, great!',
  cancelButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
  cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down'
})
```

In my code base as the follows, it behaved the same way as the `example TWO`. While clicking anywhere outside of the alert box, the alert box is gone.

How to fix it so that the alert box won't be gone while clicking anywhere outside of the alert box? What could be the version of my sweetalert ?

```
swal({
    title: "Message:",
    text: "Here is some detailed message",
    type: "warning",
    buttons: {
        to_refresh: {
            text: "Refresh the current view",
            visible: true,
            closeModal: true
        },
        to_close: {
            text: "Back to Main Menu!",
            visible: true,
            closeModal: true
        },
    },
}).then(value => {
    if (value === 'to_refresh') {
        // window.location.href = window.location.href;
        location.reload(true);
    } else {
        window.location.href = "to some other link"
    }
});
```

Comment: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on which Swal version you are using.

For SweetAlert 2:

```
allowOutsideClick: false
```

for SweetAlert (version 1):

```
closeOnClickOutside: false
```